# Full-text search with Row level security in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, security, multi-tenant, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I am working on multi-tenancy application which has implemented row-level security feature. Also, I want to perform some text based search on some of the tables which have a security policy. eg: search by SKU, Description and Customer FullName as shown in below view. Inside the SP, I am using this view to search the content by given parameters.

I know that you cannot create indexes on the views since the related tables have a security policy. My view as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwSales]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
  dbo.Sales.OrderId,
  dbo.Sales.SKU,
  dbo.Sales.Price,
  dbo.Sales.TenantId,
  dbo.Sales.Description,
  dbo.Sales.CustomerId,
  dbo.Customers.FName + ' ' + dbo.Customers.LName AS FullName
FROM dbo.Sales
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers ON dbo.Sales.CustomerId = dbo.Customers.CustomerId

GO
```

> The index on the view 'dbo.vwSales' cannot be created because the view is referencing table 'dbo.Sales' that is referenced by a security policy.

Removing the security policy from tables and add that to view not gonna work since there is a high possibility of accessing the tables from the queries. So I think the table should have the policy or maybe I am wrong.

Are there any workarounds to cater such real scenarios? (This occurs when you join multiple tables inside the view and create indexes.)